# 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 10-12: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

response = urlopen('https://tieba.baidu.com/f?kw=比特币&ie=utf-8&tab=good')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser', 'utf-8')
for anchor in soup.select('.j_th_tit'):
    print(anchor.get_text())
```

Here is the error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "index.py", line 4, in <module>
    response = urlopen('https://tieba.baidu.com/f?kw=比特币&ie=utf-8&tab=good')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 543, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1360, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1317, in do_open 
  encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1244, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1255, in _send_request
    self.putrequest(method, url, **skips)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1122, in putrequest
    self._output(request.encode('ascii'))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 10-12: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I want to crawl some texts from Baidu but it didn't work well.
I guess that the problem occurs while processing Chinese letters.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Means what it says: `ascii` is the wrong codec for content that isn't 7-bit clean. Look at the available options to `urlopen`; it should let you override the codec.

Comment: Looks like the problem is in `urlopen`, it uses `ascii` by default for encoding the URL.  Don't know enough about `urlopen` to know how to fix it.